# In the context of Morse–Kelley set theory how does truth compare to satisfaction in an unbounded class of $V_\kappa$s?

Tags: set-theory, proof-theory, large-cardinals

I've been studying Vopenka's principle:

> For any language $\mathcal{L}$ and a proper class $C$ of $\mathcal{L}$-structures, there exist distinct $M, N \in C$ and an elementary embedding $j: M \to N$.

A cardinal $\kappa$ is Vopenka if $V_\kappa$ satisfies Vopenka's principle.

Naturally arose in my head the problem of the existence of (an unbounded class of) Vopenka cardinals vs the actual truth of Vopenka's principle. By generalising this to arbitrary properties, my question is the following:

Let $\varphi$ be a formula in the language of MK set theory. Then, we define $\textrm{MK}_\varphi$ to be MK augmented by "$\varphi$ holds". Similarly, let's define $\textrm{MKL}_\varphi$ to be MK augmented by "there exists an unbounded class of cardinals $\kappa$ so that $(V_\kappa, V_{\kappa+1}, \in) \vDash \varphi$". Now, given some $\varphi$, which theory is proof-theoretically stronger: $\textrm{MK}_\varphi$ or $\textrm{MKL}_\varphi$?

Comment: Is $\varphi$ a first-order, second-order, etc. in the language of set theory?

Comment: (If you're asking about consistency strength of a set theory, you're generally *not* asking a model theory question and whether or not you're asking a proof theoretic question is also borderline. But you are definitely asking a set theory question.)

Comment: $\varphi$ is a formula in the language of MK set theory.

Comment: Yes, I get that. **But**, Morse–Kelley is a class theory, so normally we think of it as a second-order set theory, and therefore $V_\kappa$ is usually taken as the "sets" and $V_{\kappa+1}$ as the classes. Now, of course, you can just ignore all of it, and say that all the $\kappa$s in the class are successors of limits. It, does, however, change the way you look at these statements from a natural point of view.

Comment: Right. Makes sense. I will change the question then.